# Is there a way to know when a table was last accessed in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am currently working on snowflake where I need to find when a table was last accessed in snowflake either by a query or manually. Can someone help me out here? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you mean with a select, I don't think there's a way to do it by table, you'd have to monitor the last executed queries to find that information: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html

Update-wise: SYSTEM$LAST_CHANGE_COMMIT_TIME should give you the info you need.

Comment: This returns the total history of the queries that are executed..but I want to know when a table was last accessed...Can you help me with that

Comment: hi Nishanth, try something like this: select end_time, * from table(information_schema.query_history())
where query_text like '%<table_name>%'
and execution_status='SUCCESS'
order by 1 desc;

Comment: Hi Mike, it is working but presents me the history for the last 7 days is it possible to get history that is much older

Comment: For that you can refer to the query_history in account_usage, not information_schema

Answer (score 1):

[Understanding Access History](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/access-history.html#understanding-access-history)

> Access History in Snowflake refers to whether the user query reads column data. Snowflake does not record write operations. The user Access History can be found in the Access_History View (in this topic).
>
> **Each row in the ACCESS_HISTORY view contains a single record per query and describes the columns the query accessed directly (i.e. the base table) and indirectly (i.e. derived objects, such as views).** These records facilitate regulatory compliance auditing and provide insights on popular and frequently accessed tables and columns since there is a direct link between the user (i.e. query operator), the query, the table or view, the column, and the data.
>
> Additional use cases for the ACCESS_HISTORY view include:
>
> - Discovering unused data to determine whether to archive or delete the data.
> - Validating data changes to notify users prior to dropping or altering a given table or view.
> - Auditing data access to comply with regulatory requirements and data governance initiatives.

---

[ACCESS_HISTORY View](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/access_history.html)

> This Account Usage view can be used to query **the access history of Snowflake objects (e.g. table, view, column) within the last 365 days (1 year).**
>
> Using the object_id value of 32998411400350, determine when the access occurred in the last 30 days:
>
> ```
> SELECT query_id
>        , query_start_time
> FROM access_history
>      , lateral flatten(base_objects_accessed) f1
> WHERE f1.value:"objectId"::int=32998411400350
> AND f1.value:"objectDomain"::string='Table'
> AND query_start_time >= dateadd('day', -30, current_timestamp())
> ;
> ```