# How do I get the last accessed time stamp for the table in the snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to get the last accessed timestamp for a table in the snowflake

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to know when a table was last accessed in snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751428/is-there-a-way-to-know-when-a-table-was-last-accessed-in-snowflake)

Answer (score 2):

Not always ideal, but a quick way to find this for one-off questions is to use QUERY_HISTORY

```
SELECT START_TIME, * 
FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY()) 
WHERE QUERY_TEXT LIKE '%MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE%';
```

**Update**: Query to specifically get just the most recent query time. Have to filter out the QUERY_HISTORY queries themselves. This is not especailly fast, and does require that the role that's running this has access to all the relevant history.

```
SELECT MAX(START_TIME)
FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY()) 
WHERE QUERY_TEXT ILIKE '%CONFIG.PIPELINE_LOG%'
AND NOT QUERY_TEXT ILIKE '%INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY%';
```

Comment: This query giving the complete query history.But I need when the particular table name I give then I need when it has been last accessed with the time stamp.

Comment: Use the same base query that @David Garrison gave you but just change it to SELECT MAX(start_time)

Comment: its giving error with SELECT MAX(start_time) could you add the complete query.

Comment: However the above query is displaying the query history but I need when the particular table has  last accessed time stamp(last accessed details with time when I give the name of the table in query) but not a query history.

Comment: Updated with a query that returns just the time of the most recent query, instead of the full log.

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question, but I am answering it since Snowflake has added a new feature to track last access spanning 1 year. Since this information wasn't tracked from the creation of older objects, you will only see access history since the tracking started.

There is now a view in "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."ACCESS_HISTORY". You can see how to query it by flattening the `base_objects_accessed` array:

```
select * from "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."ACCESS_HISTORY",
 LATERAL FLATTEN(base_objects_accessed) limit 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this approach will help

**Important Note:** 
*Not a very suitable approach as a user must have AccountAdmin access, to run a query on snowflake.account_usage schema and query will have a bit of latency as it is part of account_usage schema. It will also incur WH cost if the data size is too big*

```
select * from "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY" 
where 
    query_text like '%STORE_SALES%' and 
    query_type = 'SELECT'
    order by START_TIME DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

[image]

Alternatively, if the requirement is limited to the last 14 days history, use the history tab which costs nothing using simple filter clauses.

[image]