# Snowflake query for the getting Info of last accessed time stamp for a table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-task

I want a particular table's last accessed time in the snowflake.

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of your previous question. [How do I get the last accessed time stamp for the table in the snowflake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60757699/how-do-i-get-the-last-accessed-time-stamp-for-the-table-in-the-snowflake)

Comment: If your prior questions are not getting answers add a comment to them.