# Snowflake - View what tables and columns are queried the most

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

is there any way within snowflake/sql query to view what tables are being queried the most as well as what columns? I want to know what data is of most value to my users and not sure how to do this programatically. Any thoughts are appreciated - thank you!

Comment: This information could be derived from [ACCESS HISTORY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67525266/5070879)

Comment: Thanks @LukaszSzozda - I added ACCESS_HISTORY to my answer (in preview right now for enterprise edition)

Comment: Hi @0004 - can you mark the existing answer as accepted? This because when I want to mark other questions as duplicate of this one, I can't -- because this one has no accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**2021 update**

The new ACCESS_HISTORY view has this information (in preview right now, enterprise edition).

For example, if you want to find the most used columns:

```sql
select obj.value:objectName::string objName
    , col.value:columnName::string colName
    , count(*) uses
    , min(query_start_time) since
    , max(query_start_time) until
from snowflake.account_usage.access_history 
    , table(flatten(direct_objects_accessed)) obj
    , table(flatten(obj.value:columns)) col
group by 1, 2
order by uses desc
```

Ref: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/access_history.html

---

**2020 answer**

The best I found (for now):

- For any given query, you can find what tables are scanned through looking at the plan generated for it:

```sql
SELECT *, "objects"
FROM TABLE(EXPLAIN_JSON(SYSTEM$EXPLAIN_PLAN_JSON('SELECT * FROM a.b.any_table_or_view')))
WHERE "operation"='TableScan'
```

- You can find all of your previous ran queries too:

```sql
select QUERY_TEXT 
from table(information_schema.query_history())
```

So the natural next step would be combine both - but that's not straightforward, as you'll get an error like:

```
SQL compilation error: argument 1 to function EXPLAIN_JSON needs to be constant, found 'SYSTEM$EXPLAIN_PLAN_JSON('SELECT * FROM a.b.c')'
```

The solution would be to combine the queries from the `query_history()` with the `SYSTEM$EXPLAIN_PLAN_JSON` outside (to make the strings constant), and then you will be able to find out the most queried tables.

Comment: I was testing along the same lines with the same findings. One possible approach to get around the requirement for a constant is running the function in a stored procedure. I don't think running the explain plan across millions of query statements will be practical, so it seems to make sense to limit them to only select statements and only running on a random sample of rows in the query history table. When I get some time, I'll work on an SP along these lines.

Comment: Exactly! Looking forward to see what you can build

Comment: Built a solution that mimics table extraction as per explain_plan but uses only SQL and joins to all query_history query_id's ... here :-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70585936/how-to-get-a-list-of-tables-used-for-each-query-in-the-query-history-in-snowflak/70589299#70589299