# extract table from query_text in history in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to know most queried table in snowflake , so want to extract table name from query_text in Snowflake_query_history table. Is there any way to do it in SQL.

Comment: Check my previous answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/64343564/132438

Answer (score 2):

Instead of parsing `query_text` you could use [ACCESS_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/access-history.html#understanding-access-history) views.

Query could look like:

```
SELECT f1.value:"objectId" AS table_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE".access_history
     ,LATERAL flatten(base_objects_accessed) f1
WHERE f1.value:"objectDomain"::string='Table'
  AND query_start_time >= dateadd('day', -30, current_timestamp())  -- last 30 days
GROUP BY table_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

The actual table name could be found in [SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/tables.html) using `TABLE_ID` column as a lookup.

Comment: Just adding a caveat to using the ACCOUNT_HISTORY view. This appears to only be available if you have Snowflake Enterprise, not Standard.

Answer (score 0):

See also: [Snowflake - View what tables and columns are queried the most](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64341885/snowflake-view-what-tables-and-columns-are-queried-the-most)

It is quite difficult to do this with high accuracy, but if it is acceptable to get reasonably close then the following may be sufficient.

This query will not handle joins, unions, subqueries, multiple CTEs, etc -- which would be difficult to do with REGEXP and would be better suited to be done in Python via the Snowflake Python connector with something like `pglast`.

```sql
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(query_text, ' from ([^\\ ]*)', 1, 1, 'ie', 1) table_name,count(*) query_count from "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY" group by 1 order by 2 desc;

TABLE_NAME  QUERY_COUNT
table_a 95
"SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY" 5
```