# Use EXPLAIN in snowflake but on the results of another query. Using it on each row of the result

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I want to get the tables used in the query_history table by using EXPLAIN on the query_text in the query_history. I know that I can give the SQL to EXPLAIN and it will give me the tables used but I need to do this over many different queries and return it all at once.

Basically I have 3 queries in the query_history table as follows:

```
select * from a.table1
select * from a.table2
select * from a.table3
```

And I need to do something like this:

```
SELECT "objects"
FROM TABLE(EXPLAIN_JSON(SYSTEM$EXPLAIN_PLAN_JSON(query_history.query_text)))
WHERE "operation"='TableScan';
```

This would return:

```
a.table1
a.table2
a.table3
```

I cannot do this in a programming language because it is going to be put into a BI tool that can only use SQL.

Comment: `EXPLAIN` can only be done one query at a time, so you'd need to create a stored procedure in Snowflake to loop through query_history and provide you the output you are looking for...or insert the results into a table in Snowflake that your BI tool can query directly.

Comment: Can you think of any way to getting all of the tables used in each query that can work with my problem? I just learned EXPLAIN but if there is a better way to solve my issue then that would be great too.

Comment: Can you be more specific on how you are getting queries from query_history? Is there a time limit? `ACCESS_HISTORY` would be the easiest answer, if available on your account https://stackoverflow.com/a/70586051/132438

Comment: I sadly can't use ACCESS_HISTORY due to my account. my data engineering team has set up a table with all information for the last 13 months for all users from table(information_schema.query_history()) so everything that is in that I will have access to query.

Comment: Oh, running `EXPLAIN_PLAN_JSON` over 13 months of queries can take a long time. I'd look for a way to do it offline, so the results can be used later for viz purposes.

Comment: Here's a pure SQL way to get what you're after ...easy peasy! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70585936/how-to-get-a-list-of-tables-used-for-each-query-in-the-query-history-in-snowflak/70589299#70589299