# Snowflake last accessed details of table & columns within a table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake how to access last accessed/last modified data for each column in a table? Like if we want to have a range of 7 day period then how to get those details.

Comment: [Is there a way to know when a table was last accessed in snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67525266/5070879)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to know when a table was last accessed in snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751428/is-there-a-way-to-know-when-a-table-was-last-accessed-in-snowflake)